# Server Actions in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using server actions in next.js as per the documentation [Server Action] https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions
My action code is

```
"use server"
export async function registerAndLoginUser(data: any) {
 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

And the action is used in a client side component

```
<form
      action={async (data: any) => {
        try {
          await registerAndLoginUser(data);
        } catch (e: unknown) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }}
    >
```

i get error

```
Type '(data: any) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2143, 9): The expected type comes from property 'action' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement>'
```

In short action property only accepts string value.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this TypeScript error by upgrading your `@types/react` package to the latest version. Experimental support for async form actions was added in `@types/react@18.0.38`